# Dependency to format values to human readable form in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, number-formatting

I am creating an app in Kotlin in android studio. I want to display values in my app so that if the number is long, let's say in millions or billions, it would truncate it and display it with a suffix, like `K`(thousand) `M`(million), *etc*.

For example: If the value was `331330464`, it would display as `331.3 M`.

Is there a dependency that allows me to do this formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've developed an extension function for `Long` class which delivers the human-readable value of it:

**HumanReadableExt.kt**

```
import kotlin.math.log10
import kotlin.math.pow

val Long.formatHumanReadable: String
    get() = log10(coerceAtLeast(1).toDouble()).toInt().div(3).let {
        val precision = when (it) {
            0 -> 0; else -> 1
        }
        val suffix = arrayOf("", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z", "Y")
        String.format("%.${precision}f ${suffix[it]}", toDouble() / 10.0.pow(it * 3))
    }
```

So, `println(331330464L.formatHumanReadable)` prints:

> 331.3 M

And for the values lower than 1000, it returns the exact number:

`println(331L.formatHumanReadable)` prints:

> 331

Comment: This is pretty good, but doesn't convert negative numbers the same way and crashes when the number is `0`.

This can be fixed with the following first line:
`get() = if (this == 0) { "0" } else log10(abs(this).toDouble()).toInt().div(3).let {`
And also `import kotlin.math.abs`

Comment: It’s fixed to cover 0 and negative values. It considers them as zero.